# Data from Twitter within given dates

Tags: twitter, twitter4j

I want to gather all tweets from twitter within specified dates. Is it possible? Is there any way to achieve it? Currently I am able to retrieve my own tweets using twitter4j.

Answer (score 1):

twitter api provides a search param called [until](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/search/tweets#api-param-search_until). you can fetch tweets with `until` param then programmatically select tweets by their date.